# How to search a list an print or return items that match?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having problems with this, basically I'm trying to search from user input an license ID, like `235467-9` and returning or printing all the items on the list that match the search.

```
def menu_2():
    print("===================================")
    print("             Tickets               ")
    print("===================================")
    vid=str(input("Enter the ID: "))
```

`user` is a list at the beginning of the program that contains sold train tickets that have the person ID, type and price, each item on the list is separated like this :

```
 [5134123-5, first class, $20], [5462112-3, business class, $10].
```

When I'm able to search the list and print if the ID was found or not, idk how to print or return the items that match the search.

To anyone able to help me with this, thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm having trouble following what you've written here. Please read this article for guidelines on sharing code examples and edit your question to follow them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know, first time posting something, someone edited it for me I think, idk how to thank him though. But now the issue is well represented.

Comment: No need to apologize, everyone has to learn at some point. Can you also share how you are searching for the ID? This looks like a homework problem to me and I want to help you learn by pointing you in the right direction, rather than just give you the answer.

Comment: I'm searching the list with a for cycle, for x in user, and down that, if x ==vid.

I've tried many different ways, but so far I've only achieved how to print if the item that I'm searching has been found or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how you solve this**

Here's the list of users

```
l = ["5134123-5", "first class", "$20"], ["5462112-3", "business class", "$10"]
```

We loop through each elements in the loop and check if the id is in the element.

```
id = input() //User input 
for i in l:
    if id in i:
        print(*i)
```

This would print the elements whose Id matched the user Id.
You could break out of the loop if the Id's are unique.